# How should I store a collection for an attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections, rails-i18n

I have `MyModel` which has attribute `category`. There are only two possible categories *Category 1* and *Category 2*. The attributes are assigned using a form as follows:

`<%= f.input :category, collection: category_options %>`

What is considered "good practice" in Rails. Should I save the attributes as a string in the db, or should I create a new table / reference for the collection?

Storing the category as a string has the benefit that it keeps the db clean, but will have to store the collections seperately in the controller. Also, since I'm using i18n, I would expect that storing the category as a string will lead to translation issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases, I usually use something like this. You can i18n the UI choices, using the internal string as the key.

```
# View Code:
# <%= form.select :role, MyModel.categories, prompt: '' -%>

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :category,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: {
              in: :categories,
              allow_blank: true }

  class << self

    def categories
      %w[hot warm cold]
    end

  end


  def categories
    self.class.categories
  end


end
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. This is a great suggestion. Question: Why would you also need the instance method? Wouldnt the class method be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

If according to business logic you are planning to have some attributes, methods or other things for each of your categories, you should create another model for `Category`. It would be less hard to implement your future needs in terms of managing complexity. If you are 100% sure that there will be no more extras about categories, you should make it an attribute with addition of some validations in your code(inclusion in `category1`, `category2`, for example).

Comment: Could you provide an example? Not sure I fully understand (newbie sorry)

Comment: @Matthias For example your categories would have some attributes as well. Maybe `size` or `price_range`, etc. Instead of storing it in every object of particular category you could store it once if your category is separate object.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The categories have no attributes of their own

Comment: @Matthias  then you should check Brad's answer. It provides an example of validation.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry to bother you. An alternative that I was thinking of was to pair the option `value` with an integer `key` and thus only store the integer in the db. This will keep some flexibility in the naming later. What do you think of this?

Comment: @Matthias could you give more detailed explanation? Did not get it.

Comment: Well you could create a hash such as `['Option 1', 0], ['Option 2', 2]`. The form would display the key `Option 1` and store the value `1` in the database. I imagine this would have some benefits, but not sure if this is customary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110172/discussion-between-maxim-pontyushenko-and-matthias).